# How to renew Google's information about my site

Tags: sitemap, hyperlink, google-search-console

I have changed a structure of my site. 
I have changed a sitemap file on googleWebmasters. 
But Google still gives me old information on search. old links.
How I can solve this problem? 
I mean, how to make Google to show new information from site?

Answer (score 2):

When have you done that change? It takes a while until Google has (re)indexed your site!
If you have submitted a new sitemap already, there is nothing you can do more. Just wait and observe as your page is being reindexed.

Comment: Yup, time to hurry up and wait.

Comment: Ok. THanks...Now I will wait.
it seems that really I have nothing to do but wait and pray :-)